# how to display the toLocaleString() in JavaScript without the GTM+... stuff?

Tags: javascript

when I use this:

```
var d=new Date();
var n=d.toLocaleString();
```

i get a result like:

```
Fri Nov 30 2012 17:02:03 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)
```

the problem: i just want to have s.th. like:

```
Fri Nov 30 2012 17:02:03
```

how to do it with javascript?

Comment: Have you tried datejs?  It allows you to format the date and time output any way you want, and in almost any language, too.

Comment: would be cool to do it with the "core" javascript, but if its not possiblt with just one function, i will try datejs. post this as a answer and i will accept it

Comment: OK, thanks, will post as answer with a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice JavaScript library called [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) that allows custom formatting and date manipulation and is free to use.  I highly recommend it for such purposes.  It even has language packs to display dates in your chosen language.